# Enabling Elasticsearch index names with illegal characters

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I am trying to create elasticsearch indexes with strings like `xxx/yyy` and `xxx yyy` but these are not permitted because they contain illegal characters (`/` and ). These names are largely user created and out of my control so changing the names for the sake of fitting into the requirements of elasticsearch is not really an option.

This is the exact error message:

```
[Error: InvalidIndexNameException[[XXX\%FFZZZ] Invalid index name [XXX\%FFZZZ], must not contain the following characters [\, /, *, ?, ", <, >, |,  , ,]]]
```

Anyways, I've tried URL encoding the strings, but that doesn't work because those include capital letters which are not permitted and backslash escaping is out of the question because it is in the list of illegal characters.

Is there a conventional solution to this problem, or do I have to come up with some sketchy serialization and/or hashing scheme to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, letting users have the control on such things like index name is asking for troubles :)

But if you're willing to pursue that route, what I suggest is simply to remove any character that is not alphanumeric and lowercase the result in the process.

In PHP that would be:

```
$index = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]+/i", "", $index);
```

In Java:

```
index = index.replace("/[^a-z0-9]+/i", "");
```

In Javascript:

```
index = index.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/i, "");
```

Comment: I think this or defining the index names yourself are really the only two options.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not allow users to define the index name. You can try to filter out illegal characters, but your regexp might have an issue, and you might run into trouble later.

Also users might not understand why they create problems if one usere uses My_Index and writes stuff in and the next user trying to access yndex accesses the same index.

BTW: The regexp given above is more strict than the list of legal characters asks for. For example _ is legal (but not at the beginning of the name), if you wanted to create a regexp that allows everything that is legal by ES standards, your regexp becomes more complicated and more error prone.